# How to get index number for a row meeting specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am curious to know how to grab index number off of a dataframe that's meeting a specific condition. I've been playing with `pandas.Index.get_loc`, but no luck.

I've loaded a csv file, and it's structured in a way that has 1000+ rows with all column values filled in, but in the middle there is one completely empty row, and the data starts again. I wanted to get the index # of the row, so I can remove/delete all the subsequent rows that come after the empty row.

This is the way I identified the empty row, `df[df["ColumnA"] ==None]`, but no luck in getting the row index number for that row. Please help!

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want is [`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

> Return object with labels on given axis omitted where alternately any
>   or all of the data are missing

If the row is empty, you can simply do this:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

If you want to find indices of null rows, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
res = df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)].index
```

To remove rows with indices greater than the *first* empty row:

```
df = df[df.index < res[0]]
```

Comment: Thanks jpp, but this only drops the one empty row in the middle and keeps all the rows that come after that empty row still in the resulting dataframe. Is there anyway I can remove all the rows that come after that empty row?(Assuming I am sure I don't need any row that comes after the empty row)